# C# OpenQA and OperaDriver() problem. No Opera at selenium OpenQA v2.5

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use OperaDriver for selenium.

```
IWebDriver wd = new OperaDriver();
```

but using OpenQA.Selenium.Opera; does not exist. I can not find it in C# dll. I am using v2.5 drivers. Chroom, Ie, Firefox exist but no Opera. Where can i get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no native OperaDriver in the .NET bindings. Opera decided to implement their driver in Java, and not to implement the RemoteWebDriver JSON wire protocol. As such the only way to use the Opera driver from .NET is to use the .NET RemoteWebDriver class, along with an instance of the standalone Java Selenium server, which is available on the project [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Windows:

The Operadriver is written in Java and not suported directly in C#, as it is mainatined not by the Selenium project team but by Opera.

To use it, you have to run the standalone Selenium webserver (from console on windows) before starting the test.  [get it here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar)

you need to set the OPERA_PATH to point to your opera.exe file. Start the server with the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
```

i use a small bat for these two tasks:

```
SET OPERA_PATH="C:\Progra~2\Opera\opera.exe"
cd C:\pathToSeleniumJarFile
C:\Progra~2\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
```

C#:
testing with remotewebdriver object in your C# code to connect to it.

```
        switch (WebBrowser)
        {
            case Browser.Chrome:
                // chromedriver.exe has to be in the debug folder
                ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
                chrome.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chrome);
                break;

            ...

            case Browser.Opera:
                //note: set OPERA_PATH environment variable (in cmd or global)
                DesiredCapabilities opera = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
                opera.SetCapability("opera.profile", @"C:\OperaProfile");
                webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(opera);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
```

if you want to manipulate the profile of the opera client (e.g. to accept untrusted certificates etc) you need to set

```
opera.SetCapability("opera.profile", @"C:\OperaProfile");
```

Copy an existing Profile to a location of your choice, here C:\OperaProfile.

==> Avoid spaces in all the pathes <==